# C# SQL DataBinder changes not saved

Tags: c#, data-binding, tableadapter

I have a data binder set up and the binding navigator and this is in the SAVE button code:

```
    private void cT_detimpBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.cT_detimpBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.BindingContext[rDataSet.CT_detimp].EndCurrentEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.rDataSet);

    }
```

I made breakpoints to be sure that the program gets to this part of the code.  I made changes to one of the fields and changed records then clicked Save.  I traced it to `tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll`  -->  to  `public virtual int UpdateAll(RDataSet dataSet)`  to `dataSet.HasChanges() == false`.  I don't know why it would be false.  I made the changes.  Please help.  I have tried it with .AcceptChangesDuringUpdate and .AcceptChangesDuringFill set at all combinations of true and false.

Comment: If by any chance you are using `.AcceptChanges()`, then remove it and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am not using .AcceptChanges() and can't find any settings for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using my own SQL to load the data.  When I took that code out of the Form_Load method and just used the dataset that I had defined using the VS dataset wizard, it worked properly.  This is all that was left in Form_Load:

```
this.cT_detimpTableAdapter.FillByErrStat(this.rDataSet.CT_detimp);
```